# Sql Error Newbie

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update the number stored in a field,this is the code I have used

```
Select * 
From MEDICATION
UPDATE medication
set seq_number = 2
where pet_id = "PO145" 
   AND vet_id = "V01" 
   AND MEDICINE ='Soothing Cream';
```

The error returned states

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you then accept the so the question could be closed. Read [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim mentioned, select and update should be different. So run them individually.

Also the strings should be enclosed in `single quotes`, not double. Although this is not the reason for error, but it will not work for you with `double quotes`. Double quotes should be used for object/column names.

Also it is a good practice to run the `where` clause used in `update` or `delete`, with `select` first, as it will let you see what rows are returned, which will be updated or deleted.

```
UPDATE medication
set seq_number = 2
where pet_id = 'PO145' 
   AND vet_id = 'V01' 
   AND MEDICINE ='Soothing Cream';
```

Comment: I have tried to use this code i now receive: ORA-00001: unique constraint (GB_A250_SQL_S19.SYS_C002703882) violated

Comment: Then you apparently have a unique constraint on the table which includes seq_number as one of its columns, and another row in the table which already contains seq_number = 2 and same values for any other columns specified in the constraint. Just as well someone put the constraint on there otherwise you would have messed up your data!

Comment: @LordPeter - Seconded. And looking at constraint name, it looks like a system constraint, so it could be on a primary key column.

Comment: Is this to stop two records having the same data?

Comment: @CallumWilson - Yes it is to stop 2 records having same `seq_number`. Please go through your data and requirement again clearly and think on why do you want to update seq_number. Although it is a huge diversion from your original question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do a `SELECT` and an `UPDATE` at the same time.  You can't do that.  For the update, just use the latter part of your query by itself:

```
UPDATE medication
SET seq_number = 2
WHERE pet_id = "PO145" AND
      vet_id = "V01"   AND
      MEDICINE = 'Soothing Cream';
```

After the update, if you want to do a `SELECT * FROM medication` then this should be no problem.